# Angular: How to get ElementRef From Custom Decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I'm implementing decorator for Host CSS Variable Binding in Angular5.
However, I can't implement it well as following code. Can I define ElementRef from decorator?

```
export function HostCssVariable(cssVariableName?: string): any {
  return (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    let _value: any;
    return {
      set: function(value) {
        // this.el is defined by TestComponent's constructor
        // Can I define ElementRef in decorator?
        this.el.nativeElement.style.setProperty(`--${cssVariableName}`, value);
        _value = value;
      },

      get: function() {
        return this.el.nativeElement.style.getProperty ?
          this.el.nativeElement.style.getProperty(`--${cssVariableName}`): _value
      },

      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    }
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  templateUrl: ...,
  styleUrls: [...]
})
export class TestComponent {

  @HostCssVariable('hoge')
  public hoge: number = 2;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What's the error? `this.el`  not defined?

Comment: No Error. But this code is not smart. I must write `constructor(private el: ElementRef)` for using this decorator.

Comment: @NozomuMiyamoto, start experimenting with a simpler example. Define a decorator that is applied to a property and inside of it add the `element` property to the class and apply the `ViewChild` decorator to it. If you succeed, migrate the logic to your custom decorator.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is a way to inject the component's ElementRef into your custom decorator, because your decorator is a Property Decorator, not a Class Decorator.